# Unable to get header values from `request_rec`

Tags: c, apache, apache2-module

### Problem

I want to retrieve value of a header in my custom Apache module. (The header is coming as part of a POST request.) I am doing this:

```c
const char *myHeader = apr_table_get(r->headers_in, "MyHeader");
```

But, this is giving `myHeader = NULL`.

### Details

I am using the `myHeader` here:

```c
sprintf(query, query_template, myHeader, 2);
```

`query` is formatted using `query_template = "call GetDelay('%s', %d)"` and executed on the DB. DB shows the executed query as `GetDelay('(null)',2)`.

**How to retrieve header values? Or what is my mistake?**

Comment: And these came in as part of the request? Or did you use say `apr_table_mergen` to add them to `headers_in`?

Comment: @sixlettervariables It comes as part of a POST request.

Comment: Your approach is correct, but you have give us more details about your module. For example, what kind of module is this, where are you trying to get the header from, the context of the apr_table_get call, etc.